# Save NodeList in JS object

Tags: javascript

I have a JS obejct and i want to save an DIV element as NodeList

```
function Wis(element, options) {
  
  this.$element = null

  setup();
}

Wis.prototype.setup = function() {
  this.$element = document.querySelector('.classname')
}
```

[image]

The item i saved is an HTMLCollection and i have no chance to add an class or add custom styling.

In other JS plugins i mentioned, that the div element was saved as NodeList

[image]

How i can save div as NodeList on JS?

I not use jquery, so i'm looking for an solution without jquery library.

Comment: You probably want `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` for a `NodeList` of all elements with the specified class.

Comment: [The ubiquitous `document.querySelectorAll()` method returns a _static_ `NodeList`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Comment: Also you'll have to call `this.setup();`